# Is Groovy xml parsing with xsd validation possible?

Tags: xml, groovy, xsd

Is it possible to validate an xml against an xsd using Groovy xmlslurper or xmlparser?
The xml I have is a simple String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not with `XmlSlurper` or `XmlParser` it isn't, but you can [still call the standard Java way from Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Validating+XML+with+a+W3C+XML+Schema):

Code adapted and pasted here from that link:

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory

String xmlString = ''' ... your xml ... '''
String xsdString = ''' ... your xsd ... '''

def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
def schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsdString)))
def validator = schema.newValidator()
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)))
```